# Using Twitter in app

Tags: java, android, twitter, status

I'm using Twitter API in my app to post status and retrieve it , I tried too many codes that was their best so far without errors.I started by posting Status but I got no errors but no status was posted

my code :

```
public class Asy extends AsyncTask<String, Void,MainActivity> {
 private Exception exception;
 public static String consumerKey = "**************";

    public static String consumerSecret = "************";


    public final static  String accesstoken= "  *************";

   public final static  String accesstokensecret="*******";

   private final String CALLBACKURL = "T4J_OAuth://callback_main";
   Twitter twitter ;
 protected MainActivity doInBackground(String... urls) {




        ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey);
        builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret);
        Configuration configuration = builder.build();
        TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
        twitter = factory.getInstance();

     try {

        AccessToken a = new AccessToken(acc,accsec);
         twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);
         twitter.updateStatus("First trial on twitter");
     } catch (TwitterException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }





        return null;


 }

 protected void onPostExecute(MainActivity feed) {
     // TODO: check this.exception 
     // TODO: do something with the feed
 }
```

}

I used asynchronous task  and I called it in my main activity by :

```
Asy task= new Asy ();
    task.execute();
```

Comment: And you question is what?

Comment: I don't know why isn't it posting and if there is a better way to update twitter status

Comment: and if there is a problem with my code ?